# django haystack KeyError when using custom search form

Tags: python, django, search, django-haystack

So I am trying to use a custom search form so that I could search by several model field separately. (like, search a equipment by asset #, by department, etc.) I have the following codes for now:

```
SEARCH_CHOCIES = (('Asset #','Asset #'), ('Calibrated by','Calibrated by'), ('Department','Department'),
 ('Description','Description'), ('Expiring soon','Expiring soon'), ('Flagged','Flagged'),
     ('Manufacturer','Manufacturer'), ('Model','Model'), ('Serial #','Serial #'), ('Test','Test'))

class MultipleSearchForm(SearchForm):
    search_type = forms.ChoiceField(required = False, choices = SEARCH_CHOCIES)
    search_content = forms.CharField(required = False)

    def search(self):
        sqs = super(MultipleSearchForm, self).search()

        if not self.is_valid():
            return self.no_query_found()
        choice = self.cleaned_data['search_type']
        content = self.cleaned_data['search_content']
        if choice:
            if content:
                if choice == 'Asset #':
                    sqs = sqs.filter(self.cleaned_data['asset_number'] == content)

        return sqs
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^search/', search_view_factory(view_class = SearchView, form_class = MultipleSearchForm), name='haystack_search'),
```

Now it only handles searching when you choose to search by asset #. Right I have these following questions:

1. when I tried to use this by going to http://127.0.0.1:8000/calbase/search/ and search by asset #, I got the following error message:

> KeyError at /calbase/search/
>
> 'asset_number'

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/calbase/search/?q=&search_type=Asset+%23&search_content=S2

Django Version: 1.10
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['calbase.apps.CalbaseConfig',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'haystack',
 'whoosh',
 'carton',
 'adminplus',
 'django.contrib.admin.apps.SimpleAdminConfig',
 'nested_inline']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\haystack\views.py" in search_view
  157.         return view_class(*args, **kwargs)(request)

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\haystack\views.py" in __call__
  49.         self.results = self.get_results()

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\haystack\views.py" in get_results
  89.         return self.form.search()

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\Documents\GitHub\equipCal\calbase\search_indexes.py" in search
  38.                   sqs = sqs.filter(self.cleaned_data['asset_number'] == content)

Exception Type: KeyError at /calbase/search/
Exception Value: 'asset_number'
```

Here I am just trying to compare the "asset_number" field of query result with the search content to find what we would like to search for. What's wrong here?

2. now in the search view, besides search type and search content that I created, there is still that old "search" field. How do I kill it?
3. For some search type, like department and test, I would like the search content field be a choice field as well so that user can choose from drop down. For all the other search type, I would like search content just be a char field. Is this doable?

Thank so much